# Insert a printf inside each function call with vim

Tags: c, debugging, vim, cscope

I am debugging `C` code for embedded systems (`backtrace` is no option) and I have this repetitive task which consists in putting a `printf` for each function call to find the real caller of my function in a specific time of code execution.

I am using `cscope` tool along with `CCtree` `vim` plugin to find the callers and it would be really helpful If someone already wrote a `vimrc` configuration for this or if there is some magical `vim` plugin that does this.

Comment: I know it is not the answer, but it may help.  If you are using `gcc`, you don't need to manually add `printf` in each function.  By using [`-finstrument-functions`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-finstrument_002dfunctions-2112) with `__cyg_profile_func_enter()` and `__cyg_profile_func_exit()`, the program should print the function entry and exit by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cscope vim plugin from [CSCOPE_MAPS](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim).

For more details on using `cscope` and `vim` refer [cscope and vim](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html)